# Show only part of coreData array

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, if-statement

I've a tableView which should only display objects of a coreData-entity if one of this entity-attribute is equal to a string.

There's a Entity called **Buy** and one of it's attribute is a string called **position**

And in my code for the tableViewController is:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *buy;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Buy"];
            self.buy= [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];  

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

And now I try to display only the objects of **Buy** which contain a **position** string equal to "a". But I don't how to write the if-condition.

Thanks to your answers in advance.

Comment: Based only on the code shown, it looks to me like you might want to use an NSPredicate in your fetch request.  It would look something like [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"position == %@", @"a"]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the following :-

```
NSString *str="a";
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@",str];
```

So, the viewDidAppear function becomes :-

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSString *str="a";
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@",str]; 
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Buy"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate : predicate ];
            self.buy= [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];  

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: nit: That should be @"a".

Comment: @sbaker Is it also possible to delete one object of **Buy**?